# Excel Auto Complete Text when typing on the Dropdown list

Tags: excel, list, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a excel input data which allows users to choose an item with Dropdown List (Done by Data Validation -> List).

However I wanted it to have a auto complete function such that when user were to key in the first few letters in the cell, the list would auto detect the suitable value for user to input. This would also solve the issue if user were to enter the wrong case for the Input (eg: Cost oF SaLe instead of Cost Of Sale as there is no validation for case sensitivity). Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: does this solution help? <http://stackoverflow.com/a/20514268/6868389> from Trigger-Cut

Comment: What have you tried? What does your research show? You're not the first person with this question and there are answers. Just search for things like "Excel autocomplete type ahead data validation". Google is your friend.

Comment: This probably what you are after: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB7aedJ9RVI

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7989763/465053) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12322328/465053). They have got solutions exactly what you are looking for.