# Autocomplete drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with a problem to autocomplete a cell based on a drop down list. I'm already using combobox but I would like to have following additional functionalities:
When typing show all possible matches on the screen and remove options which are not possible
Do this no matter where the match is found in the word, such that it's not necessary to start typing with the first character.
Example: typing "ar" will show "argument" as well as "car"

The construction of my excel is as follow:
Sheet 1 cell "C13" contains a dropdownlist generated from sheet2 Column A
Sheet 1 cells "B21-B61" and Cells "B71-B138" contain a dropdownlist generated from sheet 3 Column A --> These cells B are merged with the ones from C (don't think this will make a difference in coding).

I found some code online but it just autocompletes when I start correct with the first character of each word and also it will always display the complete list and not only the matches.
Hoping someone can help me out!

Comment: Would be useful to include the code you tried - that's an easier starting point for folks here vs. trying to guess which one of the many out there it was...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto complete when typing in drop down in Excel where list is filled using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346334/auto-complete-when-typing-in-drop-down-in-excel-where-list-is-filled-using-vba)