# I need to do a Search as you type in Excel cell. Don't need an activex control

Tags: vba, excel, dropdown

I am trying to do a search as you type in excel cell. I have a list of values from which it should show the suggestions. I was able to find the solution to do it in an active x combobox but don't know how to implement it in an excel cell.
Any help!!

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818075/excel-data-validation-with-suggestions-autocomplete There are other hits if you look for "excel vba autocomplete validation list" in google but that thread aggregates the options for you.

Answer (score 0):

data validation will do it. remove your vba tags if that answers your need. If not, then please add more info on your question.

To add this drop-down list to a sheet, do the following:

```
Create the list in cells A1:A4. ...
Select cell E3. ...
Choose Validation from the Data menu.
Choose List from the Allow option's drop-down list. ...
Click the Source control and drag to highlight the cells A1:A4. ...
Make sure the In-Cell Dropdown option is checked. ...
Click OK.
```

Comment: This solution does not search. For example: if you use data validation to limit data entry to a list of names such as `peter`, `max`, and `sarah` then it does not help to type only `s` to get `sarah` automatically selected (or show only `sarah` as the only available option starting with `s`). At least that's the case in my Excel.

Comment: Ah, I see what you want it to do now.