# Excel crash when trying to Autocomplete an ActiveX ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have an ActiveX Combobox control on a worksheet and this is the `_Change` event code

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "ItemSearch"
  Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

When I use keyboard up/down key to move through the list it automatically quits Excel.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem? I basically want a dynamic ComboBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forcing Combobox's possible values to update when you change the selected option,
that is why it's crashing.

You can try to keep `Me.ComboBox1.DropDown` in that event.

But the `.ListFillRange` should be in another event :

- Workbook_Open
- Workbook_SheetChange
- Worksheet_SelectionChange
- Worksheet_Change

---

If you're attempting to have a kind of **AutoComplete behavior**, you can use a **built-in property** :

1. Right-click on the Control, click on Properties
2. In the opened Properties window, find the `MatchEntry` property
3. Set it to `0 - fmMatchEntryFirstLetter`

Comment: But then it doesn't allows the combobox to be dynamic.

Comment: @newguy : What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: Meaning I want to filter the combobox values as I type based on what I type.

Comment: @newguy : Mkay, you are trying to use a kind of autocomplete! And trying to reinvent the wheel! ;) Set the `MatchEntry property` of the combobox to zero `fmMatchEntryFirstLetter` and if it is not enough, you have a solution detailed here : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html#a1

Comment: @R3uK Thank you very much. I was having the same problem and was getting pissed off. Hats off to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by setting ListFillRange only if no item is selected, ie

```
 If Me.TempCombo.ListIndex = -1 Then
    Me.TempCombo.ListFillRange =...          
 End If
```

This solves the error and is desirable as (at least in my case) range can only have 1 item when something is selected. So, user types for autocomplete, but when he starts using arrows he can choose from filtered so far values.

Complete example is available [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818075/excel-data-validation-with-suggestions-autocomplete/60713552#60713552) . Unlike in [this often mentioned example](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html#a1) as user types it filters out entries which don't match current input