# Autocomplete suggestion in Excel data validation list again

Tags: excel, vba, validation, autocomplete, autosuggest

How to make suggestions in Excel data validation list while typing. There are constraints in my request:

1. The list of items should be in another sheet, and must not be above in hidden rows.
2. Typing a phrase should narrow the list to all the items which contain the phrase.
3. Search should be case insensitive.

So after typing `am` we should hypothetically have a suggestion to pick up from  `Amelia`, `Camila`, `Samantha`, provided that those girls' names are on the item list.

I have found a good solution [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html), however it does not filter the items with `contains` clause but `begins with`. I sum up the proposed solution here shortly.

1. We insert a Combo Box (ActiveX Control) to a sheet.
2. We right click on a sheet name > View code > and paste the VBA code in the sheet VBA editor:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   'Update by Extendoffice: 2018/9/21
       Dim xCombox As OLEObject
       Dim xStr As String
       Dim xWs As Worksheet
       Dim xArr
       Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
       On Error Resume Next
       Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
       With xCombox
           .ListFillRange = ""
           .LinkedCell = ""
           .Visible = False
       End With
       If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
           Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
           Cancel = True
           xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
           xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
           If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
           With xCombox
               .Visible = True
               .Left = Target.Left
               .Top = Target.Top
               .Width = Target.Width + 5
               .Height = Target.Height + 5
               .ListFillRange = xStr
               If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                   xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                   Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
               End If
               .LinkedCell = Target.Address
           End With
           xCombox.Activate
           Me.TempCombo.DropDown
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
       Select Case KeyCode
           Case 9
               Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
           Case 13
               Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
       End Select
   End Sub
   ```

I could not find a way to modify to change the search option from 'begins with' to `contains`.

The questions about autocomplete or autosuggest in validation list have been asked so far.
[Excel data validation with suggestions/autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818075/excel-data-validation-with-suggestions-autocomplete)
[Excel 2010: how to use autocomplete in validation list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989763/excel-2010-how-to-use-autocomplete-in-validation-list)
But neither of them contained answers which would satisfied the constraints I imposed.

Test file for download is [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1ci8p3PESPXP5HuQmIN94AT61Vct3_zc7&export=download).

Comment: In general both, the data validation and the ComboBox don't support what you ask for. The only idea I have is to remove all items from `xArr` in a loop that don't contain the typed string eg `am`. And refresh the ComboBox list on every `TempCombo_KeyDown`. But if the list is long this could easily get very slow.

Comment: @PEH can you please put it as an answer. Which variable holds the currently typed phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following event (additionally the the other 2). Every time you enter something the code refreshes the ComboBox list.

```
Private Sub TempCombo_Change()
    With Me.TempCombo
        If Not .Visible Then Exit Sub
        .Clear 'needs property MatchEntry set to 2 - fmMatchEntryNone
        .Visible = False 'to refresh the drop down
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        Dim xStr As String, xArr As Variant
        xStr = TempCombo.TopLeftCell.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        xArr = Split(xStr, Application.International(xlListSeparator))
        Dim itm As Variant
        For Each itm In xArr
            If InStr(1, itm, .Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or .Value = "" Then
                .AddItem itm
            End If
        Next itm
        .DropDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Pops up error in the line: .List = Array() with message `Permission denied`. What is Array() ? It is empty.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Cannot reproduce it. I created a new workbook, pulled in your macros, wrote my macro, added a new ActiveX ComboBox and named it `TempCombo` and added a data validation list to the cells. That's all and it worked.

Comment: What is Array()? is it a variable? Or anything that stores data? What it refers? Is it supposed to store any data before the event fires?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin `Array()` is an empty array to reset the list.

Comment: Can it be declared before? Something like `dim Array()`

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin no [`Array()` is a VBA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function). As I said already the code works in my test file. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Is this line `.List = Array()` supposed to remove all items from the dropdown list of combobox?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin replace it with `.Clear`. But then it is necessary to set ComboBox property `MatchEntry` to `2 - fmMatchEntryNone`. For case insensitivity use `vbTextCompare` in `InStr(1, itm, .Value, vbTextCompare)` Updated my Answer.

Comment: Still no success. I have updated my answer adding a link to a test file for download (at the bottom of the answer).

Comment: Meh sorry I don't download macro enabled files from unknown sources (there is a reason why you cannot upload files here). Instead please do the following: Create a new workbook, pull in your 2 macros, pull in my macro, add a new ActiveX ComboBox and name it `TempCombo` and add a data validation list to the cells eg in column A. This worked for me.

Comment: @PEH I run into Object does not support this property of method. Do you have any reference enabled? I wonder what is wrong. Because the first VBA code, the one in my answer runs smoothly without any prompt. In your sub I think there is a problem with reference to the object. It is somehow not recognized.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin In which line do you get this error? • No references set here. Make sure your ComboBox is a ActiveX ComboBox and not a FormControl ComboBox.

Comment: The line `.Clear` . I am sure it is ActiveX. Can you upload your file? I would take the risk:-)

Comment: I got the worm. Your code works ok. However if you change the source of data validation list problems starts. Your list was defined as `Amelia,Camila,Samantha` if you change it to `=items!$A$1:$A$41` (items being a sheet name) then you will experience all weird behavior I faced.

Comment: So I assume this answers the original question and we can mark it as solution?

Comment: The constrain no 1 in my original question is not satisfied. Would you mind helping on that? I certainly will mark it as solution nevertheless.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin The issue is that it will change the question completely and probably totally mess it up. Better to close here and ask a new question on how to use a range instead of a comma separated list. Would be cleaner and other people can answer too.

Comment: I am very grateful. Thank you:-)

Comment: I couldn't use this code. It keeps giving an exception on ".Clear" even if I change my MatchEntry configuration. I've also tried to comment that, but without success.

Comment: @IúridosAnjos Please ask your own/new question showing the excact code you use. We cannot answer your question here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I noticed that The .Visible = False is firing the Lost_Focus event, how to avoid that and on the same time if i don't do .Visible=False/true the control doesn't refresh

Answer (score 0):

To overcome your first constraint, maybe you can assign a range to your combo box:

```
Dim xCombox             As OLEObject
    Dim xStr                As String
    Dim xWs                 As Worksheet
    Dim xArr
    Dim i                   As Range

    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("Combotest")
    With Sheets("Test_list2")
    Set i = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    Combotest.ListFillRange = i.Address
 Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("Combotest")
    With xCombox
        .LinkedCell = "F2"
        .Visible = True
    End With
.
.
.
.
End Sub
```